# Qt5/qml - Unable to loop video or audio

Tags: qt, loops, media-player, qml

I'm unable to loop a media (mp4 or mp3) with Qt5.4 64 bits (gcc & clang) under Ubuntu 14.04, using QML MediaPlayer. I can't even simply replay the video or audio, it can be played once, that's all.

I add that the problem does not occur under windows 7 64 bits with Qt5.3 (mingw & msvc2012).

Here the simple test code I use :

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
import QtMultimedia 5.0

 Item {
 width: 640
 height: 480

MediaPlayer {
    id: video
    loops: 2
    source : "qrc:si_blue"
}

MediaPlayer {
    id: audio
    loops: 2
    source : "qrc:check"
}

VideoOutput {
    id: output

    source : video
}

Button {
    id: btn

    width : 30
    height: 30
    onClicked: audio.play()
 }   }
```